Authorization failed for request first and then is correct
In our Backend we have several services which need to communicate. Until now they didn't have any kind of authorization. So anyone could have communicated with any service. Now we want to introduce authorization to all services. Therefor we've written the following Authorize-Attribute:
   public class BackendServiceAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
   {
       private static readonly Lazy<UserAuthorizationProvider> lazyUserAuthorizationProvider =
           new Lazy<UserAuthorizationProvider>(() => new UserAuthorizationProvider(), true);

       private static UserAuthorizationProvider authorizationProvider => lazyUserAuthorizationProvider.Value;

       public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           if (actionContext == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionContext));

           if (!IsAuthorized(actionContext))
           {
               EventLog.WriteEntry($"Backend-System", "Unauthorized request", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
               HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
           }
           else
           {
               EventLog.WriteEntry($"Backend-System", "Authorized request", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
           }
       }

       protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {

           if (actionContext == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionContext));

           return IsUserInGroup(actionContext) || IsUserAuthorized(actionContext);
       }

       private bool IsUserAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           bool isUserAuthenticated = false;

           try
           {
               string currentUserId = DoClean(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name);

               isUserAuthenticated = authorizationProvider.IsUserAuthenticated(currentUserId);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               EventLog.WriteEntry($"Backend-System", $"Exception in IsUserAuthorized: {e}\nRequest-Principal: {actionContext.RequestContext.Principal}\nRequest: {actionContext.Request}");

           }

           return isUserAuthenticated;
       }

       private const string SoftwareAdmins = "Backend-Software-Administratoren";
       private const string ServerAdmins = "Backend-Server-Administratoren";


       private bool IsUserInGroup(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           bool isInRole = false;
           try
           {
               isInRole = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal != null && (
                   actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole(SoftwareAdmins) ||
                   actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole(ServerAdmins));
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               EventLog.WriteEntry($"Backend-System", $"Exception in IsUserInGroup: {e}");
           }


           return isInRole;
       }

       private static string DoClean(string userName)
       {
           string retval = userName;
           if (retval.Contains("\\"))
           {
               string[] retsplits = retval.Split('\\');
               retval = retsplits[retsplits.Length - 1];
           }
           if (retval.Contains("@"))
           {
               string[] retsplits = retval.Split('@');
               retval = retsplits[0];
           }
           return retval.ToUpper();
       }
   }

The UserAuthorizationProvider ist just a class where the allowed user-ids are initialized once.
On each server the user where the service runs on is not member of SoftwareAdmins or ServerAdmins. So we hit the IsUserAuthorized-Method.
In the eventlog of windows on each server I see, that the IsUserAuthorized throws an Exception and then I see an entry from OnAuthorization which says: Unauthorized request. The next entry in the eventlog is Authorized request.
So I assume, that the Authorize-Attribute is called multiple times for a request.
I'm wondering if I can avoid that exception?
In the exception-message I can see that the actionContext.RequestContext.Principal is null so the call to actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity throws the exception. In the second request it must be filled.
All services provide a self hosted REST-API which is hosted using the OWIN-Framework. The configuration of the Service looks like:
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{

    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
    listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication | AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
    
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    config.DependencyResolver = controllerDependencyResolver;
    
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.EnsureInitialized();

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}

The HttpClient to consume a REST-API is wrapped in a class called 'RestClient'. To create an instance of the RestClient we use the following code:
  private RestClient GetRestClient()
  {

      RestClientSettings restClientSettings = RestClientSettings.CreateDefault();
      restClientSettings.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
      ICredential cred = CredentialProvider.GetCredential(CredentialType.BackendSystem);
      restClientSettings.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(cred.GetUserName(), cred.GetPwdSec(), "our_domain");
      RestClient client = new RestClient($"{targetUrl}", restClientSettings);
      return client;
  }

So my question is, why is the first attempt to authorize is failing and the actionContext.RequestContext.Principal is null?

I solved it by myself. I had to provider AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate
